# Why we take the element $ds$ in self inductance of coaxial cable

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I watched on a derivation of coaxial cable and when we want to calculate the self inductance per unit lengh we first find the flux of the magnetic field,so we take the integral $\int_{a}^{b}\vec{B}\cdot ds $ and we say that $ds=dr$ and my question is why it is not $rd\theta dr$ because ds  is the area of the surfate element wich is circle loop

Comment: Does this help? [Inductance of a Coaxial Structure](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Book%3A_Electromagnetics_I_(Ellingson)/07%3A_Magnetostatics/7.14%3A_Inductance_of_a_Coaxial_Structure)

Comment: ohh yes! that really helped me to understand, thanks!